# How to format multiple date values separated by commas in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

{I am using `TEXTJOIN` to concatenate a list of dates together into one cell in Excel. They are separated by commas so the output is something like:

```
43619, 43619, 43619, 43619, 43619, 43619, 43620, 43620, 43620, 43620, 43620, 43620, 43620, 43620, 43621, 43621, 43621, 43621, 43621, 43621, 43622, 43622, 43622, 43622, 43622, 43622, 43622, 43623, 43623, 43623, 43623, 43623, 43623, 43630, 43632, 43636
```

I tried normal date formatting of the cells in Excel but it only works if there is only one entry.

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(Table3[Name]=C2,Table3[DateOfInterview],""))}
```

Comment: Can you specify what format you want, e.g. "yy/mm/dd", or "yyyy-mm-dd", etc? I think you should be able to use `TEXT` and make it an array formula.

Comment: Hi BigBen, can you give me an example of this for my application? My formula is already an array formula.

Comment: `{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(Table3[Name]=C2,TEXT(Table3[DateOfInterview],"YY/MM/DD"),""))}` should do it

Comment: Fantastic M. Getrost that worked!